# "Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'"-[object Error]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a method, here I have tried to use `indexOf()` and `includes()` both. But i am getting an error message like " **Object doesn't support property or method '`includes`' "**. Even i have tried to run both IE and Chrome as well, but getting same error. If any one knows please help me.

Comment: Are you sure control.value is returning string in this case Maybe take look at type in dev tools.

Comment: it's because `str` is not a String, it's an Object. I'm fairly confident that `console.log(str+'......')` outputs `[Object object]..........`

Comment: @JeremyThille  Yes, you both are correct. It's not returning string. Thanks for help.

Comment: @asantaballa, Yes your correct, it's not returning string. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small mistake. Just convert 'control.value' into string.

```js
var str=String(control.value);
```